# How to restrict public access on Google App Engine static web site?

Tags: authentication, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want restrict public access and authenticate user whith google sign in on certain page of my GAE (standard) static web site. I tried to do it whith Access Control List but I could not managed to set public restriction... Any idea?

Comment: How much do you want to restrict its access? You can use GAE's Firewall: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls to restrict IPs, or something like Cloud IAP to restrict access to a user or group of users: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart. As for Google Sign In Auth check https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/#google_sign-in.

Comment: I want that only google id allowed could access on specific page... I'm going to trie whith Cloud IAP, thank !

Comment: You can't with IAP. IAP secure your whole AppEngine. IAP is limited to 1500 users or 100 groups (and add your users in the Group).

Comment: It's works perfectly whit Cloud IAP. As workaround I split my website in two subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) for it. 
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart